# How to import a dataframe from one module to another in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-import, importerror

I would like to reuse some columns from a dataframe which are in another module.

I want something like

**file1.py**

```
A   B
25  Hello
30  How are you
```

**file2.py**

```
A   B                 C
25  Hello            Hola
30  How are you      Como estas
```

I tried doing this, but it does not work.

**file1.py**

```
import pandas as pd
def cr():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
            'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
            'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
```

**output**:

```
    state   year    pop
0   Ohio    2000    1.5
1   Ohio    2001    1.7
2   Ohio    2002    3.6
3   Nevada  2001    2.4
4   Nevada  2002    2.9
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import cr
```

**output**

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cr' from 'file1'
```

Comment: why don't you just save the dataframe to csv file?

Comment: The import error does not match to the code you posted (`import1` vs `file1`).  I guess you edited that in between?

Comment: Thanks, I could do it. I thought of avoiding creating a newfile.csv & then importing it.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the naming here in the question. but i am actually using "import1.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file1.py**

```
import pandas as pd
def cr():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
            'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
            'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}    
    return data
```

**file2.py**

```
    import file1
    import pandas as pd
    file1.cr()
    df = pd.DataFrame(file1.cr())
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that looks good.  If you try the following

```
# file1.py          
def foo():
    print("foo")

# file2.py 
from file1 import foo

foo()
```

and then run `python file2.py` in the folder next to `file1.py` and `file2.py`, the program should actually print `foo`.

But this only works, if you execute `python`in the folder where `file1.py` and `file2.py` are located.

Comment: the both files are at same location.

Comment: yes, the important part is, that the shell that you use to run `python file2.py` is also currently in that folder.  So if you do `ls` (mac/linux) or `dir` (windows), you should see `file1.py` and `file2.py` listed there.  If not, you need to change the directory to where your files are.